# Mail setup - DKIM passes and fails in the same report

Tags: dkim, dmarc

I get a periodic mail setup report from Google DMARC support group. As far as I know, my DKIM/SPF setup is as expected for my mail server. I have tested it from MX Toolbox. Also, when I send an email from my mail server to my gmail account, I see no problem in the mail header.

However, in the Google report I receive, I see that dkim is shown as passing at one place and failing at another place (for the same IP address).

```
22     <row>
23       <source_ip>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</source_ip>
24       <count>1</count>
25       <policy_evaluated>
26         <disposition>none</disposition>
27         <dkim>pass</dkim>
28         <spf>pass</spf>
29       </policy_evaluated>
30     </row>

72     <row>
73       <source_ip>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</source_ip>
74       <count>3739</count>
75       <policy_evaluated>
76         <disposition>none</disposition>
77         <dkim>fail</dkim>
78         <spf>pass</spf>
79       </policy_evaluated>
80     </row>
```

The only difference in the two sections seems to be the "count" value. I am not sure what it stand for.

Wondering if anyone has any insight into this. Thanks.

Comment: The count value is the number of emails that match the values in that <row> tag. So in this case, they received 3740 emails during the time period, only one of which passed the DKIM checks. As for why the others didn't pass, Google only knows.

Comment: There could be multiple reasons associated with failing DKIM, some of them are automatic forwarding, dkim alignment, etc. To fix this you will have to send mails from your server and analyse the headers received